# Query SQLite with Editext value then display results in a ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

So I am currently able to view SQLite data in a ListView but it will bring back all records due to the set statement in my DB controller. But I want the user to be able to add a value into a EditText and query the database with that value then display the results into the ListView. The following are the two current pieces of code I use just incase it helps. Any help will be appreciated thanks in advance!

In my MainActivity I call this in the oncreate to display the listview:

```
public void listRecs(){

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> scanList = this.controller.getAllRecsExpDESC();

        myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, scanList, R.layout.list_view_layout, new String[]{"regNo","streetName","recExpDate","tvPosition"},
               new int[]{R.id.reg_No,R.id.street_Name,R.id.date_Time,R.id.tv_Position});

        Recs.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
```

And this is the code from my DB Controller:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllRecsExpDESC() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
        wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM recs ORDER BY recExpDate DESC";
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("regNo", cursor.getString(0));
                map.put("tvPosition", cursor.getString(1));
                map.put("streetName", cursor.getString(2));
                map.put("recExpDate", cursor.getString(3));
                wordList.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        database.close();
        return wordList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sound of things, you would take a similar function to the one you have above, but instead it takes a string parameter and uses it as part of a raw query.

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getRecsFromParameter(String PARAMETER)
```

Not sure exactly what you wanted to do but the query would be something like:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM recs WHERE Column = " + PARAMETER + "ORDER BY recExpDate DESC";
```

Otherwise this would pretty much work the same way, you'd get a list result set and would create an adapter using the list.

Important to note though, executing code based on user input does leave your application vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). You may want to additionally take measures to prevent users entering anything they want to prevent damage to the internal database.

Edit: Oh! And to get a string from an edit text you can do something along the lines of:

```
(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id).getEditableText().toString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Benjamin, ok I think I see what your getting at but what would I do from the main activity? From your post it seems as if that's all within the DB controller and I'm just wondering what I would do in the main? Would I do something like this: `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> scanList = this.controller.getAllRecsExpDESC(PARAMETER);` sorry i'm somewhat still new to this.

Comment: No worries! We were all new once. :) Finding the view/grabbing the editable text has to be done in your MainActivity code, other scopes may not have access to the edittext to be able to get the value. Otherwise, basically, yeah, you'd do the same thing as in your question but calling a different function.

Comment: Excellent it works like a treat! Thank you so much :) and I will definitely take the SQL Injection issue on-board! I will post the answer now.

Comment: Fantastic! Please accept the answer when you get a chance.